# Update ManyToManyField by calling view via ajax("Like" button)

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

Not sure if this is more of a javascript question or a django question so please forgive me if it is in the wrong spot. I am trying to update a ManyToMany field representing "likes" on an image by calling a view via ajax. The "like" portion is working, the "unlike" portion is not.

I have an Image model with a users_like field:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name = 'images_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="images_liked", blank = True)
    # etc
```

The view:

```
def image_like(request):
    image_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if image_id and action:
        try:
            image = Image.objects.get(id = image_id)
            if action == 'like':
                image.users_like.add(request.user)
            else:
                images.users_like.remove(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
        except:
            pass
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'ko'})
```

Url:

```
path('like/', views.image_like, name = 'like'),
```

html/js:

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{ image.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like" class="like button">
   {% if request.user not in users_like %}
       Like
   {% else %}
      Unlike
   {% endif %}
 </a>
<!-- other html, skipping down to the jQuery-->

{% block domready %}
  $('a.like').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('{% url "images:like" %}',
      {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        action: $(this).data('action')
      },
      function(data){
        if (data['status'] == 'ok')
        {
          var previous_action = $('a.like').data('action');

          // toggle data-action
          $('a.like').data('action', previous_action == 'like' ? 'unlike' : 'like');
          // toggle link text
          $('a.like').text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like');

          // update total likes
          var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
          $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
        }
      }
    );
  });
{% endblock %}
```

This code successfully allows a user to 'like' a post and the link subsequently changes to `<a href="#" data-id="18" data-action="unlike" class="like button">Unlike </a>`, so both the data-action and text are updating properly, but then if I click it again, it doesn't "unlike" the image. Not sure what is going here, as when the `data-action` attribute is equal to `"unlike"`, the

```
else:
  images.users_like.remove(request.user)
```

portion of the view should go into effect, it seems like the view is not being called again but I am not sure. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JQuery, but your logic *looks* okay to me.  Could it just be a typo?  I noticed an extra space between count and .total in the line `$('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);`  Are you getting any console errors in the browser?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look this over. I'm not too familiar with jQuery/using ajax and am trying to learn about it so I figured the error had to be somewhere there. I hate to say it was a typo. I used                 `images.users_like.remove(request.user)` instead of                 `image.users_like.remove(request.user)` and did not notice for a long time ...

Comment: Hi Justin, could you please share the GitHub location where you safe the codes of this application. I love your approach and I am working on a project where I need to add like and unlike to my app. Thank you.